How can Update the data form with the inertia.js formHelper in Svelte?
I have a big form with several inputs to inscribe a student, And when the user types the DNI of one of the parents I make a request through Axios, and if the DNI already exists in the database then I  take advantage of that data to fill others inputs of that parent automatically.
The problem is when I try to update the data form with that response but at the same time keep the previous info that the user typed, I can't
If I do this:
const search_rep1 = debounce(async (ci) => {
    try {
        const response = await Axios.get(
            `/dashboard/matricula/search-representative/${ci}`
        );
           
        let dataForm = $formCreate
        let updatedData = {...dataForm, ...response.data}
        $formCreate.defaults(updatedData);
        $formCreate.reset();
    }
}, 300);

<!-- the function is called when the the user type in this input into a form: -->
<Input
    type="number"
    required={true}
    label={"Cédula"}
    bind:value={$formCreate.rep_ci}
    error={$formCreate.errors?.rep_ci}
    on:input={(e) => search_rep1(e.target.value)}
/>

When the response is successful then the app gets stuck as if there is some infinite loop there

Any errors? Did you set breakpoints and check what is going on?

I can tell the problem that generate the page get stuck (forever until I close it an open it again) is here : $formCreate.defaults(updatedData); because when I do this instead: $formCreate.defaults(response.data); it fills the form properly but the problem is that also erease everything info that the user had typed before
